# Why using Binary accuracy as metric gives a higher accuracy(95%) while simple accuracy outputs low value(46%)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am doing semantic segmentation on DSTL kaggle satellite image. The masks for the classes given binary masks. when I use accuracy as metric the output is around 46% but loss (weighted binary cross-entropy loss) is round 0.073. when I use binary accuracy as metric then accuracy comes around 95%. why this kind of results are coming?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What functions are you using? From which library?

Comment: Do you have more than one class? You are probably mixing predicted classes and predicted areas. In my answer below it is explained what you should be using and the possible explanation of what is happening.

Comment: model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.0001), loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy']) gives loss= 0.0.07, acc= 0.47 and    the  when i  change to this loss= -0.76 binary acc = 0.96 model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
                       loss = dice_bce_loss, 
                       metrics = [dice_coef, 'binary_accuracy'])

Comment: yes I have more than 1 class

Comment: Binary corss entropy wouldn't make sense in the case of more that 2 clases. Refer to the post I linked in my answer. And make sure to use the proper metrics to train your algorithm

Answer (score 0):

For semantic segmentation other metrics should be used. Since we are predicting areas and classes.

Take a look at this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-to-evaluate-your-semantic-segmentation-model-6bcb99639aa2) for further understanding.

Good luck!